# Meaning of unacknowledged pre key messages

Tags: encryption, end-to-end-encryption, signal

I've recently tried to work with the Signal protocol, but the documentation isn't great. I've come across a problem where the messages being sent include the pre key because the client has unacknowledged pre key messages even if a session has already been established. I've checked the [source code](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-java/blob/master/java/src/main/java/org/whispersystems/libsignal/SessionCipher.java#L109) of the Java client, but couldn't figure out how the flag is cleared.

Can someone explain the concept behind unacknowledged pre key messages? Thank you.

Other posts (without any answer): [Signal forum 1](https://community.signalusers.org/t/what-is-unacknowledgedprekeymessage/1080), [Signal forum 2](https://community.signalusers.org/t/client-keeps-sending-prekey-message/13089), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/signal/comments/g1dws5/meaning_of_unacknowledged_pre_key_messages/)